# Call to Redirect executed but nothing happens

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Login Controller that, if the user is already logged in but still tries to get to Login Controller, redirects to the MyEvents controller.

In my code the line RedirectToAction is being executed, but nothing happens. I know you can not redirect in a Ajax call, but this is an actual GET request from another page to `/Login`. There doesn't seem to be any reason why it wouldn't redirect for me.

```vb
Function Index(Optional ReturnUrl As String = "") As ActionResult
  If HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
     RedirectToAction("Index", "MyEvents") 'This Line is being read, but nothing happens
  End If

  Return View()
End Function
```

Comment: why a down vote?? was this not an appropriate question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RedirectToAction` method doesn't actually perform the redirect, it returns a result that gets sent to the client telling it redirect. Add a `Return` and it will work.

```
Return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyEvents")
```

Comment: thanks - I actually did google a lot and found a lot of SO questions about RedirectToAction , but they were about different things